# How to add a different watermark for each page in a document?

Tags: watermark, xwatermark, draftwatermark

I want to add different text watermarks to my document, starting on the second page. The watermarks will be two-lines long, and each page will have a different watermark, as follows:

```
--- Page 2 ---
     US
United States
--- Page 3 ---
     BR
   Brazil
--- Page 4 ---
     CA
   Canada
```

The number of pages in the document is not limited to three.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believed that there are no default supports, you have to create based on `\if` or `\ifnum`

Comment: I'd suggest [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) package. Use `\AddToShipoutPicture` and `\ClearShipoutPicture` macros to set a range of pages with/without watermarks. Alternatively, [LaTeX's hook management](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf) provides info about hooks, s.a. `\AddToHook` or `\AddToHookNext`. When used with the hook `shipout/background` the effect is the same as with `eso-pic`. Here is [The ltshipout documentation](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/ltshipout-doc.pdf) for more info to understand `shipout`-related hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). `\AddToSipoutPictureBG` adds watermarks to every page from the current page onward whereas the starred version `\AddToSipoutPictureBG*` (see example with Brazil) adds one watermark only on the current page. The consecutive pages are not affected. `\ClearShipoutPictureBG` resets any picture currently used, which also has to be used in order to change a watermark unless you want to overlap multiple pictures.

I added `tikz` and `xcolor` packages. The former positions watermarks on a page and adds a few other options, such as scale, opacity or colour. The `xcolor` is to use customised colours and the `[svgnames]` option provides a great number of predefined colours (see page 39 of [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor)).

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}   % For dummy texts

\title{\bfseries The title}
\date{}
\author{First Last}

\newcommand\wm[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay]
  \node at (current page.center)
  [rotate=45, Gray, scale=5, opacity=0.35]
  {\bfseries\vbox{\centering #1}};}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\blindtext

\clearpage
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\wm{US\\United States}}
\Blindtext

\clearpage
\ClearShipoutPictureBG
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\wm{BR\\Brazil}}
\Blindtext

\clearpage
\ClearShipoutPictureBG
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\wm{CA\\Canada}}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had already solved my problem using the "background" package before I saw your answer. Anyways, I will try your solution soon!

Comment: Use whatever works for you. There are multiple solutions to your problem. However, [background](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) was not updated since 2014 whereas [eso-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) was still maintained up to 2020. This means [backgraound](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) may break sooner in future modern LaTeX.